# socket.io is confusing to me, how can I set up a connection through the same port that I already have?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Here is my app.js file, I'm not sure how to use socket.io within it and get it to function properly. Any help would be great! I've tried several different ways of writing this but I think the problem is that I am using the port for other things.

I'm requiring socket.io, then using it below, but I'm getting errors.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const hbs = require('hbs');
const socket = require('socket.io');

const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const config = require('./config/config');

const app = express();

// Load routes
const main = require('./routes/main');
const users = require('./routes/users');

// Connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect(config.db.host, {
  // useMongoClient: true
}).then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));


// Routes

// Use routes
app.use('/', main);
app.use('/users', users);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Socket.io 

var io = socket(port);
function newConnection(socket){
  console.log(socket);
}

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share the same port by attaching the same server instance that express is using to `socket.io`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server); // Pass server to it instead of port

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port);
```

Now both `express` & `socket.io` will use the same server, hence sharing the port.

You can check `socket.io` [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4) where they give a similar example.

`socket.io` can either take a port, or a `http.Server` instance, when using the former, a new `http.Server` will be created, making it impossible to use the same port, and if you try you will get:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::${port}
```

Comment: One more question, I'm serving files from a views folder that has partials in it, how would I go about hooking up socket.io? It said something about an index.html file, but I'm using an hbs file in a views folder :O

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you want to serve views with socket.io? or what is it you're trying to achieve.

Comment: When a user goes to my home page I want it to console.log something, I can't seem to get it to do that.

Comment: I'm still not sure what do you want to `console.log` you want to emit data from the server to the client, using socket.io and log that data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172544/discussion-between-bkes-and-marcos-casagrande).